# How to deal with Epic Dexterity?

Tags: scion

I'm currently DMing a Scion group which is on Demigod-level now, and I have a problem with it. Characters that push Epic Dexterity are simply overpowered and I can only really damage them if I either use tons of Epic Dex myself or give the opponents tons of Epic Strength to make them viable grapplers. That comes with another problem though, as literally none of the Epic Dex characters has Epic Stamina pushed well enough to survive a Clinch with someone of Epic Strength 7, simply by automatic successes.

I have already nerfed Untouchable Opponent and some other Dexterity knacks, but I still find myself in kind of a pickle to make battles enjoyable. So, anything I can do?

Comment: Isn't the death of a PC in Scion just an excuse to take an adventure in the underworld? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While you seem to have a grasp on the "Like Defeats Like" answer, but I have to wonder what sorts of threats the characters are supposed to be facing.  I know that for my first couple runs of Scion I typically only included mortal-style threats.  Even still, you should look into the Companion book on pg267 for the *Blast Radius* rules.  The damage for **explosive weapons** is unable to be dodged without interceding cover.  Nothing like a 15L grenade in a ten foot room.

Even still you should look into ***Co-Ordinate Assault* and *Aim*** on pg191 of Hero.  Sure the DV might be a little amped, but when there is a whole squad of SWAT troops are waiting in firing formation having trained on that door for (probably) more than a wheel's worth of ticks for a +3 to hit and Tac-Com providing their every move for a -3 or so to the Scion's DV, and they have *Automatic Fire* (Hero pg199) for up to +2 to hit and possibly a second attack each hits can happen. You might even be having them face Thralls or Einheirjar with some Courage to buff the roll. That means that with the above, an Experienced Soldier (Hero pg283) full-auto blasting the M-16 could be rolling 13 dice [=8+3+2] as a solo act. Especially when each shooter after the first is a -1DV to the target.  In a straight one on one fight Dex gets powerful but it really doesn't take much to whittle stuff like that away.

To touch once more upon the "explosive" thing, you can easily fall back on (especially without any Epic Stamina) **Environments** to do the work.  You can't "dodge" the fact that you're standing in a volcano.  Heat will get to you.  Should your opponent breathe a thick miasma into the room, (in theory) no amount of swiftness stops them from breathing and taking doses of the poison (Poison and Environment rules start on pg184 in Hero)

Additionally, not every fight should be "you guys stand over there and we'll take turns wailing on each other".  Not every foe is going to swing until their arm is missing and then keep swinging with the other.  Truly **tactical fighting** units will have fallback points.  A portion will lay suppressing fire while the others reach better cover because if the target Scion decides to dash then that's even more off of their DV. They will rarely fight to the death or when the situation is unfavorable. They have something up their sleeve, even if it's throwing a smoke grenade while wearing NVGs so even for a moment, Zippy has a -4 to their action for **Visibility**.

Look at the **boons** available.  Fertility 2 (Companion p73) is always a personal favorite if you can convince the problem Scion to, say, shake their hand or give them a really emphatic kiss with a thorny tongue.  Water 3 (Hero pg149) allows for an Environmental-based attack with steam to deal some damage. Chaos 3 (Hero pg140) doesn't even care if Dexterity is involved - which is also true for Health 4 (Demigod p80), and Moon 4 (Demigod p83).  These are simply options for barely demigods confronting them that can be potent in even small doses.  Other options include Overt Order and Serpent's Gaze as **Knacks**.

With more info I'll throw down more suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

[CatLord's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55071/28326) is pretty comprehensive, but one thing they missed is *geasa* from Companion. Specifically, an Ability Geas* for the relevant combat ability will boost accuracy without boosting damage, letting you hit your dexterous Scions without reducing them to a fine red mist. This accuracy boost can range from minor to truly massive, depending on the Legend of the one who has it and whether it's taken as a token geas (bonus dice) or a potent geas (bonus automatic successes).

As a fun bonus, it also gives roleplay requirements to the possessor, which your Scions can try to learn and exploit.

*Pronounced about halfway between "gesh" and "gish".

Arete from the Greek pantheon can also fill a similar role, but is more limited. It can only be used by a Greek Scion with at least two Legend, and only gives bonus dice. A geas can be put on anyone regardless of pantheon, even monsters or mortals, can give bonus successes, and even on a being with 0 Legend will still give one bonus.

Comment: Please reference the answer you mean directly (link if you want https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55071/28326) by user name. Votes can rearrange the order answers are presented in, so you could end up behind a different answer, or have your answer selected as "correct" and suddenly your commendation for CatLord no longer makes sense.